# Get AJAX response to display in text box

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax

After making the AJAX call to my nodejs server (using express and child processes) and sending the results back to my client how do I display this response in a text box? The correct response is being sent back when I look under the response tab of dev tools in chrome etc

```
 else
    { 
    exec( path + filename + '.exe', function ( error , stdout , stderr ){
    var out = { output : stdout};
    var err = { error : stderr};
     log(out);
    res.json(out)

    });
```

```
    $.ajax('/', {
    url: "http://localhost/server.js",
    data: { code: editor.getValue()},
    type: 'post',

   dataType: JSON,

  success : function(res){
  console.log(res);
    $('#out').val(res) //textarea call
  }

<textarea id = "#out" readonly style="padding:15px; height:209px; width:600px; " > </textarea>
```

I'm not sure how to get it to display

```
{"output":"Hello, World!"}
```

is the response I get in f12 response tab

Comment: Uh, you don't use both `res.send(out)` and `res.json(out)`.  Pick one or the other.  If you want to send data back to the client, you probably use `res.json(out)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  success : function(res){
     console.log(res.output);
     var result = res.output;
     $('#out').val(result) //textarea call
  },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, err){
         console.log('Ajax repsponse:',textStatus);
         console.log('Error',err);
  }
```

You can write like this on success call in AJAX.But make sure your res is in JSON format. If possible please add your response in your question so that I can solve your issue exactly as per your need.

Comment: Modified the code and its still not showing, added the response I get from my server, which is working as intended

Comment: I update my code @c1ic.Paste this code please and please check the console firse.If Hello world is coming in the console then you are on right path

Comment: Also please change the "id = out" instead of "id=#out" in your textarea

Comment: Its coming undefined in console? ...please console only res too..If both console is not coming then it is going in error

Comment: Okay I added error function.PLease include this in your code and check if res is going into err

Comment: still nothing, the raw response data is coming through still but nothing in console or in the text box

Comment: means in ajax success functions console you are getting anything?

Comment: I actually made an error in some other bit of code which is why the console was blank, this is what im getting now (sorry)  

 

(index):109 Ajax response: parsererror
(index):110 Error No conversion from text to [object